# datagridview using a datatable with a column href link

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, href

I'm trying to figure out how to get a bounded datagridview column in my c# winform project to show up like an href link. The thing is that the link click works but any average user wouldn't realize that they can click the field since it's displayed as a string. I need the field to show up as blue, with underlines, the mouse pointer turns into a hand ...etc.

I was able to accomplish this previously when I was using Datasets with my Datagrid. I went to the designer and selected "Add Column" and added it as a 'DataGridViewLinkColumn". I've recently changed the project to use datatables and I realized that the fields no longer show up as clickable (if I click it does work though).

Any ideal how to accomplish this with relative ease? I've searched and I'm somewhat surprised that I cannot seem to find a simple solution.

Comment: show us the code that you use to define the link column. Maybe you changed the type of the column to DataGridViewTextColumn by mistake? It supports clicks too.

Answer (score 3):

Change the type of the cells that are links to be a `DataGridViewLinkCell` and then handle the click on the cell, like this:

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (System.Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(r.Cells["Links"].Value.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            r.Cells["Links"] = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
            DataGridViewLinkCell c = r.Cells["Links"] as DataGridViewLinkCell;
        }
    }
}

// And handle the click too
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to replace the casting code in the data binding handler with `r.Cells["Links"] = new DataGridViewLinkCell { Value = r.Cells["Links"].Value };`

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
        DataGridViewLinkColumn col1 = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1);
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Links";

        DataGridViewRow dgvr = new DataGridViewRow();
        dgvr.CreateCells(dataGridView1);

        DataGridViewCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
        linkCell.Value = @"http:\\www.google.com";
        dgvr.Cells[0] = linkCell;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvr);
```

it creates a col and then a cell of type link.
you can use foreach loops to do this more orderly and faster for more items.

Good Luck!

Comment: For some reason I ended up with a new column that was empty. You did point me in the right direction though I did some searching on DataGridViewLinkColumn and was able to get it working doing something like this:

DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvlc = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();

dgvlc.DisplayIndex = 5;
dgvlc.DataPropertyName = "DataboundColumn";//bind to the correct data column
dgvlc.HeaderText = "MyLink";
this.dgvReminderSettings.Columns.Add(dgvlc);

Comment: I neglected to originally mention that this was a databound grid but I did some more searching and got this too work too. I included this part of the code above.
My only other problems is that my new column is sitting on the very left of the grid (as the 1st column instead of the 5th) and that the column can not sort like the others. I tried dgvlc.DisplayIndex = 5; to move the column over and a few other things but no luck.

Any ideal of how to fix these small but significant issues?

Many Thanks,

~ Chris

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DataGridViewLinkColumn.LinkBehavior Property. It can be set to AlwaysUnderline.

As for color, simply use the *LinkColor properties on the DataGridViewLinkColumn.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks I may try your ideals tomorrow as trying the other way I'm having trouble with the sorting and the order of the columns. Any thoughts on changing the pointer to the hand? I'm thinking to use the mouseover / mouseout and cursor.something (sorry it slips my mind). This just may work, I'll let you know. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just colour that column in the datagridview.  You could do this in a DataBindingComplete event like so:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.mydatagridview.Columns["YourLinkColumnName"] != null)
    {    
        this.mydatagridview.Columns["YourLinkColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Font = ...
        this.mydatagridview.Columns["YourLinkColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = ...
    }
}
```

You can set the font to be however you like it (ie. underlined, colored, etc.).

Alternatively, you can change the default cell style in the designer if you have the columns premade (not autogeneratedcolumns).