# c# datagridview with a column type hyperlink after db read in winform

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewlinkcolumn

i have this scenario :

after query i have this table in DataSet :

```
Name | Module | Date | Approvation
xx   |  xxx   | xxx  | xxxxxxxx
yy   |  yyy   | yyy  | yyyyyyyyy 


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //  dgvApprovazione is a datagridview
        dgvApprovazione.DataSource = dt
```

now in this situation i have at 4 columns type text(string): Name,Module,Date,Approvation...

I want column Module is a **link to file**... then *xxx* is a link, *yyy* is a link ... and other..

i have look DataGridViewLinkColumn but i don't know if that's a good way and how to set ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataGridViewLinkColumn` is the way to go, and implementing it should be as simple as:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += DataGridView1_CellContentClick;
this.dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;

private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string);
    }
}

private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells["Module"] = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
    }
}
```

Main source of this answer came from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146764/3773066), minus the conditional check.  The other answers are also informative.

Comment: ok, thanks ...
 In general i can scroll one column of datagridview ? Example ;

foreach( Row row in Datagridv.Columns[0]. **?????** )
{
   //something
}          **how??**

Comment: Are you wanting to loop through all cells of a column? If yes, you have to do it like I showed in `DataBindingComplete` - looping through all rows and accessing the cell of the desired column. Otherwise, what do you mean?

Comment: You can also loop through columns: `foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)` but that does not give you access to individual cells like looping through the rows will.

Comment: Sorry ... @OhBeWise i want scroll all cell in one single column... 
Example i have a datagridview with 4 column ... but i want scroll column[2]... and not all column. `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView.Columns[2].**methodToGetCell**)` . it's possible ?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can the `Frozen` property on a `DataGridViewRow` for vertical scrolling or a `DataGridViewColumn` for horizontal scrolling, but not individual cells. And setting `Columns[2].Frozen = true` also freezes columns 0 and 1.