# Hyperlink a URL column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

My task needs to query a searching function to take and show out the Title and URL of webpages into DataGridView from Database.

The DataGridView looks like this:
[image]

My problem is i don't know how to hyperlink the URL column. And after clicking these URLs, my Web browser in C# ( i completely coded a Web browser and now is the searching interface) can open it.

Here is my code to query and input the data from Database:

```
mcon.Open();                   
MySqlDataAdapter mda1 = new MySqlDataAdapter
    ("SELECT Title, URL FROM document WHERE MATCH(Title) AGAINST ('%" + keyword + "%') LIMIT 10", mcon);
MySqlDataAdapter mda2 = new MySqlDataAdapter
    ("SELECT Title, URL FROM document WHERE MATCH(Content) AGAINST ('%" + keyword + "%') LIMIT 10", mcon);               
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
mda1.Fill(dt1);
mda2.Fill(dt2);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
mcon.Close();
```

Comment: you need to write code on in the `DataBinding` event that will build the URL / Hyper link. you could also do this using the `ItemTemplate`

Comment: inside of the `<asp:DataGrid>` you can add an ItemTemplate like this 
`<ItemTemplate>
   <a href='<%#Eval("URL") %>' >URL</a>
</ItemTemplate>` I currently do this using email addresses to show in a DataGrid.. if you want to see an example I can post an example under the answer..

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16146764/3773066) might help.

Comment: @MethodMan Can you post this example on the answer? i think it may help me to solve this. Thank you so much!

Comment: @OhBeWise thank you, i have read before ask this question but still get stuck.

Comment: @MethodMan i really need your example, please show me asap. Thank you so much !