# how to add link in my DataGridView in c# windows form?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

Hi I save address of user file in database and i want when user click on them the file from their system is open.

this is my linq queay:

```
public IEnumerable<object> readPaging(int page, int perPage, string search = null, string searchType = null)

{

    DB db = new DB();
        var q = (from i in db.Contentss
                 select new
                 {
                     image = i.image,
                     title = i.title,
                     address = i.address,
                     date = i.date
                 }
                           ).OrderByDescending(i => i.date).Skip((page - 1) * perPage).Take(perPage).ToList();
        return q;
    
}
```

and this is my function for fill datagrid view:

```
  private void dataGridFill(IEnumerable<object> list)
    {

    dataGridViewX1.DataSource = null;
    //dataGridViewX1.DataSource = list;
    dataGridViewX1.RowTemplate.Height = 150;

    // image Column
    DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    dataGridViewX1.Columns.Add(imageColumn);
    imageColumn.HeaderText = "تصویر";
    ((DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridViewX1.Columns[0]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
    dataGridViewX1.Columns[0].Width = 150;
    imageColumn.Name = "image";

    // link Column
    DataGridViewLinkColumn titleColumn = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
    dataGridViewX1.Columns.Add(titleColumn);
    titleColumn.HeaderText = "عنوان";
    titleColumn.Name = "title";

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        int index = dataGridViewX1.Rows.Add();
        

        dataGridViewX1.Rows[index].Cells["image"].Value = (byte[])item.GetType().GetProperty("image").GetValue(item, null);

        string text = (string)item.GetType().GetProperty("title").GetValue(item, null);
        string link = (string)item.GetType().GetProperty("address").GetValue(item, null);

        string linkHtml = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + text + "</a>";
        dataGridViewX1.Rows[index].Cells["title"].Value = linkHtml;




    }
}
```

---

**PROBLEM**
I want show the title as text and address as link so user can click on them and open the file.
But after run the gridview show my the linkHtml content and when I click on it nothing happened and no file is open.
how can fix this?
notice: the file can every type, but most of them is txt and doc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146764/14171304

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick?view=netframework-4.8.1) you can use `DataGridView.CellContentClick` or `DataGridView.CellClick` events to open file or handle other logic.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkColumn && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        //object value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        //File.Open()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I going to try this. but in my own code, even when I change the local address with website link (link google.com) the webpage not open ether

Comment: I try your code. my problem solved, But I still interest to find the answer to the question I asked in the comment above.

Comment: you can open files by `File.Open(filePath);`, Open url in default browser by `Process.Start(url);` and open url in chrome by `Process.Start("chrome", url);`.